# TimePicker in Remove Set time option in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, androiddesignsupport, android-timepicker

Android Time picker in can't remove set time option

I have checked Stack Overflow questions & also check some option remove keyboard set time icon, but not remove that options,  keyboard icon When click keyboard icon for open set time edittext and then clock icon visible for, I want to remove set time edit option in Time picker Android.

[image: Time Picker : rect in highlight icon]

[image: keyboard icon click when visible clock icon]

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you cannot remove this icon, it is part of the UI on Android O.

In Android O, the time picker (in Calendar, Clock, etc) gets one small added icon at the bottom left: a keyboard. Tapping it switches to text-based entry where you can manually type in the exact time.

if you want really remove it you should create your own `TimePickerDialog` , read more about this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021466/how-to-disable-keyboard-in-timepickerdialog-android)